# Sharepoint web part content blocked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have inserted a web part on a Sharepoint (2010) page that displays contents from another web page. This displays fine in Chrome, but neither works in Internet Explorer nor Firefox. The web page by itself (navigated in a different tab/window) works fine, but not when it is displayed as a web part.

Internet Explorer - error message:

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate. For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help.

Firefox - error message:

> Your connection is not secure. The owner of  has configured
>   their website improperly. To protect your information from being
>   stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

Is this a Sharepoint problem (since the web pages don't work in the Sharepoint web part) or other problem? And is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Sharepoint was set up as an HTTP site and the content I was trying to get displayed was from an HTTPS web server, so the real issue here was mixed HTTP and HTTPS content. The browsers didn't like this, so they didn't display content in the web part. I don't know why Chrome didn't block the content. To solve this, I gave the web part an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is not sharepoint problem rather it is issue with I.E. Enhanced security which is causing the issue.

You can disable the certificate check from IE to disable it or use the below link for other options

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_other/error-content-was-blocked-because-it-was-not/7528770d-0031-49ea-a61f-201b1958eb15?auth=1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I unchecked "Check for server certificate revocation" in Internet Options and restarted, as described, but the web part still blocks the content. I'd like to reiterate that the website i'm trying to display in the web part works in a separate IE or Firefox tab, when browsed to.